# httpwebrequest is not waiting for my response

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have a JavaScriptHelper class with a custom WebPost method as follows:

```
public string WebPost(string url, string json)
        {
            #region

           string responseData = "";
            try
           {
                HttpWebRequest webRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;

                StreamWriter requestWriter = null;
                webRequest.Method = "POST";
                webRequest.ContentType = "application/json";

                using (requestWriter = new StreamWriter(webRequest.GetRequestStream()))
                {
                    requestWriter.Write(json);
                }

                using (StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    responseData = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
                }

                webRequest = null;
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                LogBase.LogController.WriteError(ex);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                LogBase.LogController.WriteError(ex);
            }
            return responseData;
            #endregion
        }
```

I use this to send a POST request to an ASP.NET WebAPI service as follows:

```
RegisterModel model = new RegisterModel();
model.email = "abc@gmail.com";
model.oAuthId = "11111111";
model.oAuthType = "Facebook";

string jsonStr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);
string response = new JavaScriptHelper().WebPost("http://localhost:9091/api/Authentication/authenticateoauth", jsonStr);
```

The service receives this call. If the user exists, it returns the response, if it doesnt, it creates the user and returns the response.

The problem I am facing is that when the user exists, everything works fine. I get the response on the client (JSON). When it doesn't exists, it creates the user correctly on the server, but my client breaks off early and doesn't wait for a response. I get the following error:

```
System.Net.WebException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
  Source=System
  StackTrace:
       at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
```

How can I force my request to wait for a response a little longer?

Comment: HTTP 500 means internal server error. There is an error/exception in your .NET sources. Fixing this error will probably call the correct handler (the one that you expect) in Javascript.

Comment: thanks for the help. I found a self referencing loop.

Comment: I was going to say set some debug points and step through the code.